# Getting Photos of contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursoradapter

I'm working on getting contacts through cursor. Everything is working fine, but displaying contacts photos is not returning anything. I'm not getting any crash or error. My code is

ContactListActivity.java

```
Cursor cur= getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);
        list.setAdapter(new contactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cur));
```

My custom created cursor adapter is

```
class contactAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

        String Name, phoneNumber;
        private Cursor cursor;
        private Context ccontext;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public contactAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            cursor = c;
            ccontext = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.contactsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
                holder.ContactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                holder.contactCheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_check);
                view.setTag(holder);
                holder.contactCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        cb.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
//                      ContactPerson selected = (ContactPerson)cb.getTag();
                        Log.d("selcted", cb.getTag().toString());
                        if(cb.isChecked()){

                            phoneID.add(cb.getTag().toString());


                        }
                    }

                }); 
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
//          Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)));
//          Log.d("ImagePath", ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_FILE_ID);
            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
               byte[] photoByte = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("data15"));

                if(photoByte != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte, 0, photoByte.length);

                    // Getting Caching directory
                    File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                    // Temporary file to store the contact image
                    File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID))+".png");

                    // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                        // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                        // Flush the FileOutputStream
                        fOutStream.flush();

                        //Close the FileOutputStream
                        fOutStream.close();
                        holder.contactsImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   String photoPath = tmpFile.getPath();
                   Log.d("photoPath", photoPath);
                }
            }
//          holder.contactsImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            holder.ContactName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            holder.contactCheck.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
            holder.contactCheck.setChecked(false);

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox_item, arg2, false);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          Log.d("don't know", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            return super.getView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        }

    }
```

Can anybody please tell me where I'm going wrong and guide me to get the photos. I google everywhere and implemented code. But none of them yielded required result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you can get image from contact URI.

```
String image_uri    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));   
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(image_uri)); 
contactpic.setImageBitmap(bitmap) ;
```

Comment: It is showing like "12-27 15:39:26.387: E/CursorWindow(21442): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 100, numColumns = 63
"

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
private void getContactsDetails() {

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String Name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String Number = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            String image_uri = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

            System.out.println("Contact1 : " + Name + ", Number " + Number
                    + ", image_uri " + image_uri);


            if (image_uri != null) {
                 image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(image_uri));
                }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below method to fetch the contact name and contact photo.

```
private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * super fast query to pull email addresses. It is much faster than pulling
     * all contact columns as suggested by other answers...
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<ContactVo> getNameEmailDetails() {
        ArrayList<ContactVo> m_arrList = new ArrayList<ContactVo>();
        ArrayList<String> emlRecs = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashSet<String> emlRecsHS = new HashSet<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = m_context.getContentResolver();
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };
        String order = "CASE WHEN " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, "
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ", "
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
                + " COLLATE NOCASE";
        String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
                + " NOT LIKE ''";
        Cursor cur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
                filter, null, order);
        ContactVo m_vo;
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                m_vo = new ContactVo();
                // names comes in hand sometimes
                String name = cur.getString(1);
                String emlAddr = cur.getString(3);
                System.err.println("Value Is---------->" + cur.getString(2)
                        + "Name--" + name + "Email---" + emlAddr);
                m_vo.setM_sName(name);
                m_vo.setM_sEmail(emlAddr);
                // keep unique only
                if (emlRecsHS.add(emlAddr.toLowerCase())) {
                    emlRecs.add(emlAddr);
                }
                m_arrList.add(m_vo);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

        cur.close();
        return m_arrList;
    }
```